# Как можно разделить список python?

Tags: python, list

Пытаюсь разделить список на составные части. Возможно я не в том направлении иду?

Есть файл test.txt с содержимым:

```
             
                               

смена # 5902 (ККТ:#331)
  38.Mannol Classic 10W-40
                       380,00 р                   <---- типа цена***
  ост:    21.00
 прод:     1.00     380,00 р.
  47.Gleid Master -30 жид.
                       350,00 р
  ост:     2.00
 прод:     1.00     350,00 р.

Итого:              730,00 р.
```

Код:

```
with open('test.txt') as inp:
    massiv=inp.read().split()
del massiv[0:4]
print(massiv)
```

Вывод:

```
['38.Mannol', 'Classic', '10W-40', '380,00', 'р', 'ост:', '21.00', 'прод:', '1.00', '380,00', 'р.', '47.Gleid', 'Master', '-30', 'жид.', '350,00', 'р', 'ост:', '2.00', 'прод:', '1.00', '350,00', 'р.', 'Итого:', '730,00', 'р.']
```

А мне нужно вывести раздельно, но ничего не получается.
Не к чему привязаться, т.к. код товара постоянно изменяется, название тоже, а структура не изменна.
И рубли `**₽** ост:, прод:` убрать хочу. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Вы не подумайте, я правда до последнего пробовал, но получалось черти-что.
Не хочу портить вопрос своими примерами.

Идеал:

```
a = ['38', 'Mannol Classic 10W-40', '380,00', '21.00', '1.00', '380,00']
b = ['47', 'Gleid Master -30 жид', '350,00', '2.00', '1.00', '350,00']
c = ['730']
```

Напомню, что товар может изменяться.

Comment: .txt всегда имеет точно такой формат?

Comment: Да позиции цифр, и названия не меняется. (В названии стоит ограничения при вводе. Максимум одна строка на название.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Жестко захардкодил, но иногда и такое требуется. Поскольку по условию задачи файл вот такой и никакой другой

Я добавлю переменную с содержанием файла и прочитаю создам список через `splitlines`.

```py
test_txt = """
смена # 5902 (ККТ:#331)
  38.Mannol Classic 10W-40
                       380,00 р
  ост:    21.00
 прод:     1.00     380,00 р.
  47.Gleid Master -30 жид.
                       350,00 р
  ост:     2.00
 прод:     1.00     350,00 р.

Итого:              730,00 р.
"""
initial_list = test_txt.splitlines()
```

Аналагом для чтения из файла будет

```py
f = open("test.txt", "r")
initial_list = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

Содержание переменной `initial_list`

```py
['', 'смена # 5902 (ККТ:#331)', '  38.Mannol Classic 10W-40', '                       380,00 р', '  ост:    21.00', ' прод:     1.00     380,00 р.', 
'  47.Gleid Master -30 жид.', '                       350,00 р', '  ост:     2.00', ' прод:     1.00     350,00 р.', '', 'Итого:              730,00 
р.']
```

Поскольку один элемент занимает 4 строки и начинается со следующей после строки которая содержит `смена`, то найдем начало и обрежем список

```py
for i in initial_list:
    if "смена" in i.lower():
        initial_list = initial_list[initial_list.index(i) + 1:]
```

Содержание переменной `initial_list` теперь

```py
['  38.Mannol Classic 10W-40', '                       380,00 р', '  ост:    21.00', ' прод:     1.00     380,00 р.', '  47.Gleid Master -30 жид.', '                       350,00 р', '  ост:     2.00', ' прод:     1.00     350,00 р.', '', 'Итого:              730,00 р.']
```

Разобъем `initial_list` на части равные одной записи, которая равняется 4 строкам или 4 членам списка и поместим в переменную `items`

```py
items = []

while len(initial_list)>4:
    items.append(initial_list[0:4])
    initial_list = initial_list[4:]
```

Создадим функцию, чтобы "причесать" наши элементы

```py
import re

def combing(item):
    res = []
    begin = item[0].split(".")
    res.append(begin[0].lstrip())
    res.append(begin[1])
    res.append(item[1].split()[0] )
    res.append(re.findall(r'\d*\.\d+|\d+', item[2])[0])
    res.append(re.findall(r'\d*\.\d+|\d+', item[3])[0])
    res.append(re.findall(r'[\d]+,[\d]+', item[3])[0])
    return res
```

Прогоним через нее и посмотрим на результат

```py
result = []

for i in items:
    result.append(combing(i))
```

переменная `result` содержит

```py
[['38', 'Mannol Classic 10W-40', '380,00', '21.00', '1.00', '380,00'], 
 ['47', 'Gleid Master -30 жид', '350,00', '2.00', '1.00', '350,00']]
```

Вроде то, что надо.

Плюс сама переменная `initial_list` будет содержать

```py
['', 'Итого:              730,00 р.']
```

По аналогии тоже можно обработать