# Как сократить код Python

Tags: python, циклы, инспекция-кода

Вот собственно код и тут все видно.
Хотелось бы автоматизировать через цикл.
Но обратите внимание, последняя строка при выводе имеет только дату, как удалять такие не полные строки автоматом?
Так же товара может быть больше, но структура строк не меняется.

```
import sqlite3

add = []
test = []
test.append(['32', 'AGA Антифриз Z40', '38', 'Mannol Classic 10W-40', '42', 'Fenom Очиститель карб', '47', 'Gleid Master -30 жид']) 
test.append(['250,00', '380,00', '200,00', '350,00']) 
test.append(['7.00', '22.00', '17.00', '25.00']) 
test.append(['2.00', '500,00', '1.00', '380,00', '1.00', '200,00', '1.00', '350,00']) 
test.append(['06-04-21'])

for i in range(1):
    a1 = test[0:5][0][0:2],test[0:5][1][0:1],test[0:5][2][0:1],test[0:5][3][0:2],test[0:5][4][0:1]
    a2 = test[0:5][0][2:4],test[0:5][1][1:2],test[0:5][2][1:2],test[0:5][3][2:4],test[0:5][4][0:1]
    a3 = test[0:5][0][4:6],test[0:5][1][2:3],test[0:5][2][2:3],test[0:5][3][4:6],test[0:5][4][0:1]
    a4 = test[0:5][0][6:8],test[0:5][1][3:4],test[0:5][2][3:4],test[0:5][3][6:8],test[0:5][4][0:1]
    a5 = test[0:5][0][8:10],test[0:5][1][4:5],test[0:5][2][4:5],test[0:5][3][8:10],test[0:5][4][0:1]

res1 = []
res2 = []
res3 = []
res4 = []
res5 = []
for x in a1:
    res1.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])
for x in a2:
    res2.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])
for x in a3:
    res3.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])    
for x in a4:
    res4.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])
for x in a5:
    res5.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])

add.append(res1)
add.append(res2)
add.append(res3)
add.append(res4)
add.append(res5)
print()
print()
print(add)
```

```
[['32', 'AGA Антифриз Z40', '250,00', '7.00', '2.00', '500,00', '06-04-21'],
['38', 'Mannol Classic 10W-40', '380,00', '22.00', '1.00', '380,00', '06-04-21'],
['42', 'Fenom Очиститель карб', '200,00', '17.00', '1.00', '200,00', '06-04-21'],
['47', 'Gleid Master -30 жид', '350,00', '25.00', '1.00', '350,00', '06-04-21'],
['06-04-21']]
```

Comment: как вы получаете исходные списки? может сразу их как-то оптимальнее можно организовать?

Comment: Да вот пожалуйста, посмотрите. https://replit.com/@YanWolf/FunctionalIdealisticExabyte#main.py

Comment: это продолжение [квеста с чеками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274986/420098)? дайте другую ссылку на файл RF104883.004 (у меня он почему-то с вопросами вместо кирилицы)

Comment: Да оно самое, но я доплыл все же до формирования списков) https://text-host.ru/bez-zagolovka-166

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще в одну строчку делается. :)

```
test = [['32', 'AGA Антифриз Z40', '38', 'Mannol Classic 10W-40', '42', 'Fenom Очиститель карб', '47', 'Gleid Master -30 жид'],
        ['250,00', '380,00', '200,00', '350,00'],
        ['7.00', '22.00', '17.00', '25.00'],
        ['2.00', '500,00', '1.00', '380,00', '1.00', '200,00', '1.00', '350,00'],
        ['06-04-21']]

result = [[el for grp in it for el in grp] + test[-1] for it in zip(*[zip(*[iter(test[i])]*n) for i, n in enumerate([2,1,1,2])])]

from pprint import pprint 
pprint(result, width=len(str(result))-1)
```

```
[['32', 'AGA Антифриз Z40', '250,00', '7.00', '2.00', '500,00', '06-04-21'],
 ['38', 'Mannol Classic 10W-40', '380,00', '22.00', '1.00', '380,00', '06-04-21'],
 ['42', 'Fenom Очиститель карб', '200,00', '17.00', '1.00', '200,00', '06-04-21'],
 ['47', 'Gleid Master -30 жид', '350,00', '25.00', '1.00', '350,00', '06-04-21']]
```

Comment: А это вообще не ответ, это бомба)) Прям в дюдечку, то что нужно. Спасибо, очень признателен!

Comment: @YanWolf Ещё немного оптимизировал строчку. :)

Comment: Спасибо, может посоветуете курсы по python?

Comment: @YanWolf Увы, по курсам я не специалист. Питон - у меня далеко не первый язык, так что я просто читал документацию (синтаксис) + тупо примеры и техники в чужом коде.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import sqlite3

add = []
test = [['32', 'AGA Антифриз Z40', '38', 'Mannol Classic 10W-40', '42', 'Fenom Очиститель карб', '47',
         'Gleid Master -30 жид'], ['250,00', '380,00', '200,00', '350,00'], ['7.00', '22.00', '17.00', '25.00'],
        ['2.00', '500,00', '1.00', '380,00', '1.00', '200,00', '1.00', '350,00'], ['06-04-21']]

a1 = test[0:5][0][0:2], test[0:5][1][0:1], test[0:5][2][0:1], test[0:5][3][0:2], test[0:5][4][0:1]
a2 = test[0:5][0][2:4], test[0:5][1][1:2], test[0:5][2][1:2], test[0:5][3][2:4], test[0:5][4][0:1]
a3 = test[0:5][0][4:6], test[0:5][1][2:3], test[0:5][2][2:3], test[0:5][3][4:6], test[0:5][4][0:1]
a4 = test[0:5][0][6:8], test[0:5][1][3:4], test[0:5][2][3:4], test[0:5][3][6:8], test[0:5][4][0:1]
a5 = test[0:5][0][8:10], test[0:5][1][4:5], test[0:5][2][4:5], test[0:5][3][8:10], test[0:5][4][0:1]

res1 = res2 = res3 = res4 = res5 = []

for x in a1:
    res1.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])
for x in a2:
    res2.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])
for x in a3:
    res3.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])
for x in a4:
    res4.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])
for x in a5:
    res5.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])

""""
Выше можете заменить и попробовать так:
[res1.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]) for x in a1]
[res2.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]) for x in a2]
[res3.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]) for x in a3]
[res4.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]) for x in a4]
[res4.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]) for x in a4]
[res5.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]) for x in a5]
"""

add.append(res1)
add.append(res2)
add.append(res3)
add.append(res4)
add.append(res5)
print()
print()
print(add)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я ожидал немного другого. А точнее сокращений в районе работы среза строк т.к. вся проблема возникает именно там. a1,a2 ......

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [[] for _ in range(5)]
n = m = 0
for i in range(5):
    arr[i] = [test[0:5][0][n:n+2], test[0:5][1][m:m+1], test[0:5][2][m:m+1], test[0:5][3][n:n+2], test[0:5][4][0:1]]
    n += 2
    m += 1

for i, item in enumerate(arr):
    add.append([])
    for x in item:
        add[i].extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])
```